# listview alternative to smoothScrollToPositionFromTop in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scroll

I need to set the firstVisibleItem. right now when I use `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop` there seems to be some visible scrolling (of course). I am drawing a blank on what the alternative method is. I have used it before, but I just can't seem to find it. Basically instead of smooth scrolling, it "instantaneously" sets the position that I select plus whatever offset I pass it. Does anyone remember which method does this? It's something like

```
 listView.setAsTop(position, offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AbsListView#setSelection(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection%28int%29):

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(position);
   }
});
```

Make sure `listView` and `position` are member variables or declared as `final`.